# SyntaxError: invalid syntax python

Tags: python

`cd "C:\Python"`

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Хочу создать путь для открытия файлов .py через cmd, но выдаёт ошибку синтаксиса.
Что не так? (я новичок и только начал изучать python)

Comment: Попробуйте ' cd "C:\\Python"'

Comment: вы пытаетесь запускать OS команды в интерпретаторе Python - так это не работает. Для этого есть соответствующие аналоги в Python.